# how to deal with file without a name in linux?

Tags: linux

I'm a green hand to linux using the vmware called Parallels on my mac and the edition I use is CentOS7.When I use the `ls -al` command, I found some files don't have name as follow in surprise:[image]

I just want to know as these files are seemingly generated at a same time, what are they? how to delete them?

Comment: You can get this kind of behavior if the name consists of non-printable characters. However, I don't know how they got created in your machine... Try opening them with a text editor like emacs to see what they contain

Comment: if you type this : ls -l $'\177' does it print something ?

Comment: @ Tarek,just shows no such file or directory

Comment: @randombee, that works,thx!It's really some folders in Japanese characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On *nix system every file has an atrribute called i-node. You can find with command

```
ls -i
```

when you have i=node number you can delete file by

```
find . -inum 782263 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

You could use any other commands not only rm.

more details you can find here
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/delete-remove-files-with-inode-number.html

Answer (score 0):

As the `d` in `drwxr-xr-x` states, those are folders (or at least the filesystem thinks they are). You may use [Midnight Commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/) to delete them. You may already have it installed on your machine, try to run `mc` to see if it's there.

Comment: what you said works, and what's wrong with it is the name of it is in Japanese characters and can't be printable